# How to calibrate accelerometer sensor on Google Nexus 6P?

Tags: sensors, calibration

when building an application for Android, I've noticed that the rotation vector sensor gives readings that are off. The phone's rotation is reported a little bit tilted.

When investigating, I found that the accelerometer pointing along the x-axis is offset by approximately `-0.02`.

Here is a chart of the coordinate axis to help the issue:

[image: Android sensor coordinate frame]

Here is a picture of the measurements I took:

[image: Measurements]

First, I assumed an device-specific hardware issue, but the issue is still present on a second replacement device.

Is this issue known? How could I calibrate the sensor to remove the offset?

Comment: You've got this too? I also noticed this when using Google Cardboard. It slowly moves away to a side, and after time it moved a whole circle.

Comment: The issue for cardboard is probably just gyro drift which is quite normal. With this issue, however, the horizon is tilted.

Answer (score 1):

I have this too, and likewise it has persisted after getting a replacement device. It interferes with panoramas and photospheres, cardboard and the like. No idea on a fix. I think I'll do a second replacement.